# activiti execution.setvariable not working in task listener

Tags: java, spring, workflow, activiti, bpmn

Good day.

I created a variable instance 'TaskAssignee' which will be utilize across task and flow.
TaskAssignee will store the task assignee name and show it in the next user task (via form).
I used the execution.setVariable inside the task listener but it didn't work.
How am i able to do it?

Here is the code :

```
<process id="GetAssigneePerTask2" name="Get Assignee Per Task" isExecutable="true">
<documentation>undefined</documentation>
<extensionElements>
<activiti:executionListener event="start" expression="${execution.setVariable(&quot;TaskAssignee&quot;, &quot;MyData&quot;)}"/>
<modeler:executionvariables xmlns:modeler="http://activiti.com/modeler" modeler:variableName="TaskAssignee" modeler:variableType="string"/>
</extensionElements>
<startEvent id="startEvent1"/>
    <userTask id="sid-F533EC22-E107-49D2-ABDE-AE3BA402E8A4" name="Show Task User" activiti:assignee="$INITIATOR" activiti:formKey="2661">
      <extensionElements>
        <modeler:allow-send-email>true</modeler:allow-send-email>
        <modeler:form-reference-id>2661</modeler:form-reference-id>
        <modeler:form-reference-name>Show Data form</modeler:form-reference-name>
        <modeler:initiator-can-complete>true</modeler:initiator-can-complete>
      </extensionElements>
    </userTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-F6A4A4AA-3075-4FA2-BE69-5109B340E3A8" sourceRef="sid-CB8D41DC-E2C6-4D60-A247-62630B0EF758" targetRef="sid-F533EC22-E107-49D2-ABDE-AE3BA402E8A4"/>
    <endEvent id="sid-C23D6404-68B8-4C5C-8469-562C63E363AA"/>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-70DA56B6-5156-4CF1-8B36-DE0CB28096C5" sourceRef="sid-F533EC22-E107-49D2-ABDE-AE3BA402E8A4" targetRef="sid-C23D6404-68B8-4C5C-8469-562C63E363AA"/>
    <userTask id="sid-CB8D41DC-E2C6-4D60-A247-62630B0EF758" name="Get User of this task" activiti:assignee="$INITIATOR">
      <extensionElements>
        <activiti:taskListener event="complete" class="org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.listener.ScriptTaskListener">
          <activiti:field name="script">
            <activiti:string><![CDATA[var dataValue = task.assignee;
execution.setVariable("TaskAssignee", dataValue);]]></activiti:string>
          </activiti:field>
          <activiti:field name="language">
            <activiti:string><![CDATA[javascript]]></activiti:string>
          </activiti:field>
        </activiti:taskListener>
        <modeler:allow-send-email>true</modeler:allow-send-email>
        <modeler:initiator-can-complete>true</modeler:initiator-can-complete>
      </extensionElements>
    </userTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-9B8DB7EE-D9CD-4FA8-96C8-ED62ECED5404" sourceRef="startEvent1" targetRef="sid-CB8D41DC-E2C6-4D60-A247-62630B0EF758"/>
  </process>
```

BTW i'm using activiti 5.19.

Comment: When you say it's not working, can you provide more details. Is the variable not being created, or is it being created with a value you dont expect?

Comment: @GregHarley i use the execution.setVariable("TaskAssignee", dataValue) to capture the assignee to the variable TaskAssignee. TaskAssignee variable is created in the Process Variable section. 

The value of the task.assignee is not passed to the TaskAssignee variable via execution.setVariable.

Comment: `task.getAssignee()` will give you userId of the assigned user.

Comment: can i use this under form javascript?

Comment: @christinesarsonas yes